# SqlDataAdapter and The transaction log for database is full

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to update/insert huge number of data into a database

I'm using the following code:

```
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
                command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameters)
                    command.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);


                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.InsertCommand = command;
                adapter.UpdateBatchSize = batchSize;

                return adapter.Update(table);
            }
```

and i'm using the following stored procedure:

```
    @shareAdGroupId int,
@groupPermissionName varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN transaction
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.@permissionTypeName

    declare @permissionId int
    EXEC  [dbo].[PROC_UPSERT_PERMISSION] @permissionName = @groupPermissionName,  @permissionId = @permissionId OUTPUT


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN TRY
        begin
            INSERT INTO [dbo].SHARE_AD_GROUP_PERMISSION
           (SHARE_AD_GROUP_ID,PERMISSION_ID)
        VALUES
           (@shareAdGroupId,@permissionId)
        end
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --RETURN ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    END CATCH
commit transaction
```

After inserting/updating a random number of record, i get the error:

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction log for database 'dbName' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases*

I know this question has been asked many time, however I searched to find out if the way I'm updating/inserting is causing the issue.

Since I'm not a DBA and I have no rights on the db server, I cannot modify the backup logs, however I don't really care if the issue is only that. Then this is up to the dba to solve it.

My question is, in the coding part, am I doing something wrong, can I improve that somehow?

Thanks

Comment: What is the recovery model of your database? If you have a DBA you should have him look into this.

Comment: Recovery model is set to FULL, but i don't have the rights to change that neither to shrink the database, if the only solution is to modify this, then i don't really care since it's up to the dba to manage that. i'm only concerned with the coding part

Comment: Yep, this is a problem for the DBA, they need to run a transaction log backup on this DB to clear it out. Then the file can be shrunk or the disk extended depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, this error is only fixable on the DBA end, so there isn't anything you can really do without rights. either the volume that the disk is on is running out of space, the log file has hit its quota, or the auto-growth for the log file is not set correctly.